# Transform text selected in a Textbox selected with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to transform the selected text in a TextBox when I press a shortcut, as shown in the picture (the example is adding tags but it could be a different change):

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: please share the code you have written. I can't really understand what are you asking.

Comment: I don't write code.. I do not understand why you give negative points. My question is clear. Sort events in the picture, how to coding?

Comment: `-4 and vote to CLOSE`If you don't write code..then why are you asking the question..sound ridiculous to me..

Comment: they reduce code because you need to show that you have tried, share some code. don't just ask everyone to code for you.

Comment: Are you sure you carefully read the question?

Comment: Tried to express what I understood from the picture and your comments. Feel free to revert my change if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `TextBox.KeyUp` event

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyValue == 49)
    {
        if (textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            textBox1.SelectedText = String.Format("<h1>{0}</h1>", textBox1.SelectedText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me the logic. But, This code did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In textbox selected event you should handle following insructions:

1. Get text from textbox
2. Save it to array or something like that
3. Give HTML tags and give array inside HTML tags
4. Set it to screen again

Comment: HTML tags objects just example. I do not know the logic. Logic and want to learn how to do. Thank you..

Comment: you can do it like @AppDeveloper did